# How to send a simple number and receive in URL only in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a YouTube player on a page. I create a variable for the index

```
var playlistIndex;
playlistIndex = player.getPlaylistIndex();
```

Next, I open a new window with this saved index

```
window.open ('http://blog.isvn.pl/MusicPlayer?index='+playlistIndex,'', '')
```

This works, I have a URL with ID of playlist index.

How can I copy this number from URL to a some variable on another page where I also have a YouTube player?

I want to send the playlist position in URL and insert it to another player. It is possible? How? I don't understand `GET` and `POST` and I don't know how it works. I didn't find a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

put the code on the newly opened tab where you want to get the index

```css
var parameter = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" ); // will return the GET parameter 

var values = parameter.split("=");

alert(values); // just to check the value

var index= values;
```

Comment: why this recive some number and coma before this number? Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QOxeg5B.png